# Annualization in MDX

Tags: mdx

**Introduction**
Currently I'm doing a maintenance job on a measure which annualizes another (YTD) measure. The granularity of measures is month. The annualization works fine on month level, but when we use parents in the date hierachy the calculation does not work.

It should work like this:

```
MeasureAnnualized = YTDMeasure * (CurrentMonth / 12)
```

CurrentMonth is implemented as

```
ClosingPeriod([Date].[DateHierarchy].[Month], [Date].[DateHierarchy]).MemberValue
```

On month level this works fine:

```
Month       MeasureYTD  MeasureAnnualized   ClosingPeriod
july        -50        -85,71               7
august      -60        -90,00               8
september   (null)      (null)              9
```

But on a higher level in the DateHierarchy this does not work. For instance on Quarter level:

```
 
Quarter     MeasureYTD  MeasureAnnualized           ClosingPeriod
3           -60         -80,00 (should be : -90,00) 9 (should be: 8)
```

As you can see, it picks the ClosingPeriod of quarter 3 (=9) whereas this should be the last "non-empty" ClosingPeriod (=8). The same applies to Year level:

```
Year        MeasureYTD  MeasureAnnualized           ClosingPeriod
2016        -60         -60,00 (should be : -90,00) 12 (should be: 8)
```

**The question therefore is:** how can I get this ClosingPeriod to be the last Period in which the YTD measure is not (null)?

Comment: surprised this works: `ClosingPeriod([Date].[DateHierarchy].[Month], [Date].[DateHierarchy]).MemberValue` according to the definition (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145584.aspx) the 2nd arg should be a member expression  -so it must be assuming that `[Date].[DateHierarchy]` is something else, maybe `[Date].[DateHierarchy].[All]` or `[Date].[DateHierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition on msdn of `ClosingPeriod` it gives an equivalent nested version of the same logic:

```
Tail(Descendants(Member_Expression, Level_Expression), 1)
```

The below is similar to this with an added `NonEmpty`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER Measures.[LastNonEmpty] AS 
    Tail
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month])
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
     ,1
    ).Item(0).MemberValue 
SELECT 
  Measures.[LastNonEmpty] ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!!! For the annualization of QTD values I also need to convert the result of your solution (the last non-empty month of year) to a "month of quarter". For example: 3 > 3, 4>1, 12>3 et cetera. I noticed MDX does not have a modulus function, any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Rutger here you go: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18186.mod-function-in-mdx.aspx (feel free to up useful answer and mark them correct if you're satisfied)